# How to change indentation of lambdas for Erlang in spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, erlang, indentation, spacemacs

No matter what I try I can't make lambdas indent with 4 spaces. They always land with 8:

```erlang
fun() ->
        8
end
```

instead of desired

```erlang
fun() ->
    4
end
```

I tried adding to my user config following variables:

```lisp
(setq-default erlang-indent-level 4
              erlang-indent-guard 2
              erlang-argument-indent 2)
```

But it didn't make any difference. I also tried `setvar` and `setq`. How to force spacemacs to indent lambdas using 4 spaces?

Comment: I'm not familiar with erlang, but I found `fun() ->` indent with 8 space while `hello() ->` indent with 4. Is there any reason behind it? Is fun a reserved word?

Comment: fun defines a lambda, otherwise you make a toplevel function